# How to maniplate values in input boxes with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, input, user-input

I was developing a feedback system in my webpage, in which the user inputs name, email adress, and the feedback.

I made a "Discard" button in it. On clicking it, you get a confirmation message saying "Discard this draft?". I wanted the values in input boxes to be cleared if "Ok" is clicked, and the values to remain the same if "Cancel" is clicked.

But whether I click "Ok" or "Cancel", the input boxes always go blank.

Here's the code:

```js
document.getElementById("discard").onclick = function() {
  var choice = confirm("Discard this draft?");

  var Name = document.getElementById("name");
  var Email = document.getElementById("email");
  var Feedback = document.getElementById("feedback");

  var nameValue = Name.value;
  var emailValue = Email.value;
  var feedbackValue = Feedback.value;

  if (choice == null) {
    Name.value = nameValue;
    Email.value = emailValue;
    Feedback.value = feedbackValue;
  } else if (choice != null) {
    Name.value = "";
    Feedback.value = "";
    Email.value = "";
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter your email" required><br><br>
  <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Enter your name (optional)"><br><br>
  <textarea type="text" id="feedback" placeholder="Enter the feedback..." required></textarea><br><br>
  <button id="discard">Discard</button>
  <button id="send">Send feedback</button>
</form>
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Resetting the values does not make any sense, or am I missing something?

Comment: To ferikeem's point - you only need to handle the "OK" for discard - no need to set the values to themselves if the user cancels.

Answer (score 3):

`confirm()` returns `true` or `false` so your `choice` value will be boolean.

That's why `choice != null` is always `true` and your input boxes always go blank.

Answer (score 0):

The result of `confirm` will never be `null`

`confirm` returns a boolean (`true` or `false`) indicating whether OK or Cancel was pressed.

Your if-statement has to be updated:

```js
 if (choice === false) {
     Name.value = nameValue;
     Email.value = emailValue;
     Feedback.value = feedbackValue;
 }
 else {
     Name.value = "";
     Feedback.value = "";
     Email.value = "";
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I think you mean "choice == false" instead of "choice === false".

Comment: I don't :) 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness

Answer (score 0):

Instead of null use false.
So your code should be like this

```js
document.getElementById("discard").onclick = function() {
  var choice = confirm("Discard this draft?");

  var Name = document.getElementById("name");
  var Email = document.getElementById("email");
  var Feedback = document.getElementById("feedback");

  var nameValue = Name.value;
  var emailValue = Email.value;
  var feedbackValue = Feedback.value;

  if (choice == false) {
    Name.value = nameValue;
    Email.value = emailValue;
    Feedback.value = feedbackValue;
  } else {
    Name.value = "";
    Feedback.value = "";
    Email.value = "";
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter your email" required><br><br>
  <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Enter your name (optional)"><br><br>
  <textarea type="text" id="feedback" placeholder="Enter the feedback..." required></textarea><br><br>
  <button id="discard">Discard</button>
  <button id="send">Send feedback</button>
</form>
```